# Simple text maze solver that starts from middle point doesn't end when finding first exit

Tags: java, algorithm

I searched for a problem close to mine but every maze has some starting or finishing points or starts from the edge of the maze. I want to find the first exit possible starting from the middle of teh maze and print the maze with the route to the exit. For example I have maze like this:

```
XXX XXXXXX
XX  XXX XX
XX XXX  XX
XX XX  XXX
X      XXX
XXXX XXXXX
```

And we start from the middle point:

```
XXX XXXXXX
XX  XXX XX
XX XXX  XX
XX XX* XXX
X      XXX
XXXX XXXXX
```

Then I think that the exit should be like this:

```
XXX XXXXXX
XX  XXX XX
XX XXX  XX
XX XX* XXX
X   ** XXX
XXXX*XXXXX
```

But instead I get something like this:

```
XXX XXXXXX
XX**XXX XX
XX*XXX  XX
XX*XX* XXX
X **** XXX
XXXX*XXXXX
```

Also If I input bigger maze for example:

```
XXX  XX
X     X  X
X XX  XX X
X   XXX
X    X  XX
XX  XX  X
   X  X X
X   X   XX
X XXXX XXX
XX  XX  XX
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 7
    at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:48)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:712)
    at Labyrinth.initializeMaze(Labyrinth.java:37)
    at Start.main(Start.java:3)
```

And I don't really know what the problem is. My code looks like this.
Start.java(starting class)

```
public class Start {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Labyrinth.initializeMaze("simplemaze.txt");
        Labyrinth.printMaze();
        if (Labyrinth.solveMaze(Labyrinth.startrow, Labyrinth.startcol))
            Labyrinth.printMaze();
        else
            System.out.println("Unsolvable");
    }
}
```

Labyrinth.java(solving class)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Labyrinth {
    private static char [][] maze;
    static int startrow;
    static int startcol;
    private static ArrayList<String> mazeBuffer;

    public static void initializeMaze (String fileName) {
        startrow = startcol = -1;

        mazeBuffer = new ArrayList<String>();
        int numcols = 0;
        try {
            Scanner file = new Scanner (new File(fileName));
            while(file.hasNext())
            {
                String nextLine = file.nextLine();
                mazeBuffer.add(nextLine);
                if (nextLine.length() > numcols)
                    numcols = nextLine.length();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(fileName + " has an issue");
        }
        int numrows = mazeBuffer.size();
        System.out.println(numrows);
        System.out.println(numcols);
        maze = new char[numrows][numcols];
        for (int r = 0; r < numrows; r++){
            String row = mazeBuffer.get(r);
            for (int c = 0; c < numcols; c++){
                if (row.length() >= c)
                    maze[r][c] = row.charAt(c);
                else
                    maze[r][c] = 'X';
                if (r==numrows/2 && c==numcols/2 && row.length() >= c){
                    startrow = r;
                    startcol = c;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Maze loaded");
    }
    public static void printMaze(){
        for (char[] row: maze){
            for (char c: row)
                System.out.print(c);
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static boolean solveMaze(int r, int c){
        if (r < 0 || c < 0 || r >= maze.length || c >= maze[0].length)
            return false;
        if (maze[r][c] == ' ' && r == mazeBuffer.size() || maze[r][c] == ' ' && r == 0 || maze[r][c] == ' ' && c==0 || maze[r][c] == ' ' && c==10)
            return true;
        if (maze[r][c] != ' ' && maze[r][c] != 'S')
            return false;
        maze[r][c] = '*';
        if (solveMaze(r-1,c)){
            maze[r][c] = '*';
            return true;
        }
        if (solveMaze(r+1,c)){
            maze[r][c] = '*';
            return true;
        }
        if (solveMaze(r,c-1)){
            maze[r][c] = '*';
            return true;
        }
        if (solveMaze(r,c+1)){
            maze[r][c] = '*';
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I modified it because at the start the program would get from point S(start) to point F(finish), but I want it to print the maze with first found route to exit without using any obvious points in the maze file itself. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the program required to find *the nearest* exit or is it OK when it prints *the first exit that it finds*?

Comment: @OleV.V. It's ok when It print the first exit.

Comment: Where have you used `S` or `E`?

Comment: @AKSingh S was a starting point and E was a exit. Now I want my program to find and print first exit starting from the middle of the maze without using this 2 points(S,E).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your observed output you notice the asterisk in the bottom row.

```
XXXX*XXXXX
```

So your solver has made it this far. But apparently has not discovered that there’s an exit here and hence has continued searching.

The problem is in this line:

```
    if (maze[r][c] == ' ' && r == mazeBuffer.size() || maze[r][c] == ' ' && r == 0 || maze[r][c] == ' ' && c==0 || maze[r][c] == ' ' && c==10)
```

`mazeBuffer` has size 6 and the rows are indexed 0 through 5. So when `r` is 5 and pointing to the last row, it is not equal to the size, and `solveMaze()` does not return true on this occasion. Instead it keeps searching until it find an exit to the top or left.

Instead you probably want:

```
    if (maze[r][c] == ' ' && r == mazeBuffer.size() - 1 || maze[r][c] == ' ' && r == 0 || maze[r][c] == ' ' && c==0 || maze[r][c] == ' ' && c == maze[r].length - 1)
```

Now the output is:

```
XXX XXXXXX
XX  XXX XX
XX XXX  XX
XX XX* XXX
X   ** XXX
XXXX XXXXX
```

Your method never prints the asterisk at the exit where it exits. I am leaving it to you to fix that detail.

Furthermore I believe that I was right in my comment:

> Before returning false you should probably set `maze[r][c]` back to
> whichever value it had before (would that be `' '` always?)

Comment: Ok I got it, but I have the second problem. When I input the second maze(10x10) I get String index out of range: 7 error at the 37th line . Do you maybe know why ? The numrows and numcols are equal to 10 so the index shouldn't give an error, bit It does.

Comment: No, I can’t readily reproduce that one. Which line is line 37?

Comment: Ok I got It. The middle of the maze was an X. Thank you for help!